# Johnson filtration and lower central series

Tags: gr.group-theory, automorphism-groups, kernels

Let $G$ be a group and consider the lower central series:
$$G=\gamma_1 G \geq \gamma_2 G=[G,\gamma_1 G]\geq \gamma_3G=[G,\gamma_2G]\geq\cdots.$$

Let $S_g^1$ be a compact oriented genus $g$ surface with one boundary component and $\pi$ be $\pi_1(S_g^1,*)$ for a base point $*$ in the boundary component.
Then there are natural homomorphisms $\mathrm{Mod}_g^1\rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(\pi)$ and
$\psi_g^1[k]:\mathrm{Mod}_g^1\rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(\pi/\gamma_k\pi)$.

The $k$th term of the Johnson filtration of $\mathrm{Mod}_g^1$, denoted by $J_g^1(k)$, is the kernel of $\psi_g^1[k+1]$.
Then $J_g^1(1)=I_g^1$ is the Torelli subgroup of $\mathrm{Mod}_g^1$.

Even though it is known that $\gamma_k I_g^1\leq J_g^1(k)$ for all $k$, I cannot prove it or find any reference. I hope to know how to figure it out.